# Real time filtering of a table

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Little Things</title>
<?php echo link_tag('resources/css/style.css'); ?>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url('resources/js/script.js');?>" ></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">var $rows = $('#table tr');
$('#search').keyup(function() {
    var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

    $rows.show().filter(function() {
        var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
        return !~text.indexOf(val);
    }).hide();
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
        <div id="top">
        <img id="logo" src="<?php echo base_url('resources/images/logo.jpg'); ?>" alt="litLogo"/>
        </div>
        <div id="main">
        <div id='cssmenu'>
<ul>
   <li class='active'><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/LittleController/index');?>"><span>Home</span></a></li>
   <li class="element"><a href='#'><span>Shopping Cart</span></a></li>

   <li class="element"><a href='#'><span>Wish List</span></a></li>


   <li class="element"><a href='#'><span>Contact</span></a></li>
    <li id="name">
    <?php 
        if($this->session->userdata('email'))
        {
            echo "<a href='#'><span>Welcome ".$user."!</span></a>";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "<a href='#'><span>Welcome Guest!</span></a>";
        }
         ?>
            <?php
        if($this->session->userdata('email'))
        {
            echo '<li class="element"><a href="'.base_url("index.php/LittleController/logout").'"><span>Logout</span></a></li>';
        } 
        else
        {
            echo '<li class="element"><a href="'.base_url("index.php/LittleController/login").'"><span>Login</span></a></li>';
        }
        ?>
    </li>
       <li class="element"><a href="<?php echo base_url('index.php/LittleController/signup');?>"><span>Sign Up</span></a></li>
</ul>
</div>
<div class="tables" id="tables">
<input type="text" class="search" placeholder="Type to search">
    <?php
     $imgDir="../../resources/images/thumbs/";
        echo "<table id='table'>";
        echo "<tbody class='list'>";
        echo "<tr bgcolor='#E60000'>";
        echo "<th>Name</th><th>Product Line</th><th>Product Scale</th><th>Product Description</th><th>Price</th><th>Image</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $i=0;
        foreach($Products as $key => $value)
        {
        $i++;
            if($i%2==0)
            {
                echo "<tr bgcolor='#EE4D4D' width='100%'>";
                //echo '<td>'.$value["ID"].'</td>';
                echo "<td class='pName'>".$value["productName"]."</td>";
                echo "<td class='pLine'>".$value["productLine"]."</td>";
                echo "<td class='pScale'>".$value["productScale"]."</td>";
                echo "<td class='pDes'>".$value["productDescription"]."</td>";
                echo "<td class='buyPrice'>".$value["buyPrice"]."</td>";
                //echo '<td>'.$value["QtySold"].'</td>';
                echo "<td class='image'><img src='".$imgDir.$value['image']."' height='100' width='100'/></td>";
                //echo '<td>'.$value["ABV"].'</td>';
                echo "</tr>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<tr bgcolor='#F28080' width='100%'>";
                //echo '<td>'.$value["ID"].'</td>';
                echo "<td class='pName'>".$value["productName"]."</td>";
                echo "<td class='pLine'>".$value["productLine"]."</td>";
                echo "<td class='pScale'>".$value["productScale"]."</td>";
                echo "<td class='pDes'>".$value["productDescription"]."</td>";
                echo "<td class='buyPrice'>".$value["buyPrice"]."</td>";
                //echo '<td>'.$value["QtySold"].'</td>';
                echo "<td class='image'><img src='".$imgDir.$value['image']."' height='100' width='100'/></td>";
                //echo '<td>'.$value["ABV"].'</td>';
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        }
        echo "</tbody>";
        echo "</table>";

    ?>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var options = {
  valueNames: [ 'pName', 'pLine', 'pScale', 'pDes', 'buyPrice','image' ]
};

var userList = new List('tables', options);</script>
        </div>
        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

So this is my code. I am trying to filter the table as I am typing into the text box. Any help appreciated.

I've tried following the tutorials but they do not seem to work at all... any ideas?

I find it difficult to understand and apply to my own website, the code I have for filtering is taken from the internet is well.

Comment: Filter the table how? Less rows? Less columns? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Your question is very broad, please expand on what you're asking.

Comment: There is a really great plugin called Datatables that makes it easy to build "smart tables" capable of sorting, filtering, etc.  You can have a look at https://datatables.net/

Comment: Okay. Now, this is a list of products in a shop with toys, with pagination, 10 per page. As i type I would like to reduce the number of rows to only those which match the search criteria. Please and thank you

Comment: I do not want to use datatables as if I select stuff from db, I need to use $this->table->generate() in CodeIgniter and this is restricting me to having all columns from db in my table - which I do not want at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see you're using jQuery so why not use contains selector? You could use it after keyUp event on select tag:

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
  var search = this.value;
  $('#table tr, #table th').show();
  $('#table td:contains('+search+')').each(function(){
     $(this).parent().hide();
  });
});
```

This code will hide any cell parent (tr, th...) which have a child td containing input value . You can use this code and make it fits better your needs.

Fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/uby9quLo/2/

Hope it helps!

Comment: but I got no select tag, what do you mean by it?

Comment: Whoops! I wanted to make reference to your search input haha! Change it for #search and it should work ;)

Comment: Sorry, another mistake. keyup must be on lowercase. Here an example: http://jsfiddle.net/uby9quLo/2/